# EF4 CodeFirst CTP5 nvarchar(max) via attribute

Tags: entity-framework-4, data-annotations, ef4-code-only, fluent-interface, code-first

Is there a way to create a custom attribute that will make EF CodeFirst use **nvarchar(max)** as datatype when assigned to a property of a poco class? I know this is possible via fluent api, but we would like to have all definitions within one place and thats the metadata class.

Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>().Property(p => p.TicketText).HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class NVarcharMaxAttribute : Attribute { }

public class NVarcharMaxAttributeConvention : AttributeConfigurationConvention<PropertyInfo, StringPropertyConfiguration, NVarcharMaxAttribute> {
    public override void Apply(PropertyInfo memberInfo, StringPropertyConfiguration configuration, NVarcharMaxAttribute attribute) {
        configuration.ColumnType = "nvarchar(max)";
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<NVarcharMaxAttributeConvention>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLength]
```